# Why is Tippecanoe conversion of geojson file to pbf vector tiles resulting in incorrect lat/long placement?

Tags: mbtiles, tippecanoe

I'm trying to generate pbf vector tiles from json data using tippecanoe. Ultimately will be served up for use in OpenLayers but had no success there so tried testing the tiles in QGIS.  When I view any of them (in QGIS) instead of being in the longitude range of -180 to +180 they are in the ~2000 to ~4000 range.

I have a simple json file consisting of a rectangle surrounding Europe using EPSG:4326.
I use tippecanoe to generate the pbf tiles.

jim.json consists of:

```
{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[0,0],[0,80],[80,80],[80,0],[0,0]],"type":"LineString"},"properties":{"level-index":1,"level-value":956.0,"stroke":"#a52a2a","stroke-width":1,"title":"956.00 "},"type":"Feature"}],"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type": "name","properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}
```

Then I run this command:

```
tippecanoe --no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit --no-tile-compression -s EPSG:4326 --output-to-directory TilesDir --force jim.json
```

Then if I try to see if the tiles are correct, I take the largest one (0/0/0.pbf) into QGIS and the rectangle gets plotted outside of the earth out at 2000degE instead of in the expected area near Europe.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that QGIS is not the appropriate tool to test the pbf. After correcting some other issues, I was able to display the pbf in OpenLayers. I assume tippecanoe generates the pbf with some internal coordinate system (4096x4096 pixels?) not the EPSG:4326 that I was expecting.